# SQLAlchemy syntax for GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY on postgres database

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

How could the following table be represented as an SQLA model?

```sql
CREATE TABLE x
(
    x_id    integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    x_name  text unique
);
```

I think that if I create a column using:

```py
    id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
```

The generated SQL won't use `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`, but will instead use `SERIAL`.

Completing the following, in order to use the `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` syntax, is what I'm unsure of:

```py
class X(Base):
    __tablename__ = "x"
    x_id = Column( <something here> ) 
    x_name = Column(Text, unique = True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [`Identity`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/defaults.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Identity) in your column definition.

```py
class X(Base):
    __tablename__ = "x"
    x_id = Column(Integer, Identity(always=True), primary_key=True)
    x_name = Column(Text, unique=True)
```

**PS.** no need to set `nullable=False` if you set `primary_key=True`.

Comment: Thanks - and this will generate raw sql with `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` rather than `serial` ?

Comment: Well yes, that's what you asked for, see [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/defaults.html#identity-ddl) for more examples.

Comment: Sorry it does - just checked - thank you :) (i had some other sqla code which created a `series`). Thanks for the link too